# Problema con slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

El problema es que cuando quiero ponerme en la barra de búsqueda se me oculta de nuevo y no se como hacer que se quede cuando estoy encima de ella.

```
    <div style="display: none;" class="input-group mb-3" id="barra">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..."/>
    <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-dark fas fa-search" type="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

El script de Jquery que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buscador").hover(function () {
        $("#barra").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

El id "buscador" hace referencia a un elemento de una lista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo más fácil en tu caso es crear un `div` `container` que contenga tanto al enlace como al `input` y que hagas *bind* al evento hover de dicho `container` en vez de al `#buscador`. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").hover(function (e) {
        $("#barra").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="buscador">Buscar</div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="input-group mb-3" id="barra">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..."/>
      <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-dark fas fa-search" type="button"></button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edito**
Ojo con el `width` del `container`. Tendrás que ajustarlo a tu contenido para que no ocupe todo el ancho y se lance el hover cuando no quieres.